# Assemble, Convene A Conference

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, word-usage

Is the verb 'assemble' sloppily used as 'convene' here:

> [link 1](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/05/12/world/middleeast/12jerusalem.html)
>   "Mr. Husseini was speaking at a ***hastily assembled news conference*** in the mainly Palestinian Sheikh Jarrah neighborhood of East Jerusalem, after the closing of the media center in the nearby Ambassador Hotel. "
>
> [link 2](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/10/01/world/asia/suspected-insider-attack-in-afghanistan.html)
>   "At a ***hastily convened news conference*** on Sunday, the deputy ISAF commander, Lt. Gen. Adrian Bradshaw, read a brief statement that did little to clarify what happened between the ISAF and Afghan National Army, or ANA, soldiers."

Dictionaries suggest "to convene a group of people" and "convene a conference/meeting" are okay.  But only "to assemble a group of people" okay, and not "to assemble a conference/meeting".

Comment: _Assemble_ brings to mind Ikea furniture and other horrible images.

Comment: If conferees may be the objects of convention, why not of assembly? AHD: "To bring or call together into a group or whole: *assembled the jury*." And a news conference is only nominally a conference; nobody confers.

Comment: So is a news conference, nominally! I like *assemble* better than *convene* here: *convene* suggests something formal and carefully prepared, while *assemble* gives a better sense of "slapped together".

Comment: @StoneyB But a 'conference/meeting; is an activity.  For the verb 'convene' dictionaries have two senses where 'convene' is followed by people or the activity of a conference. [definition of convene](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/convene)  For the verb 'assemble', dictionaries only have one sense, where 'assemble' is followed by people only.  [definition of assemble](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/assemble)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's fine. I'm not surprised that you've found dictionaries are explicitly giving "convene a meeting" but not "assemble a meeting", because *assemble* is a wider word and a lot of things one can *assemble*, one cannot *convene* (or at the very least, it would be a strange wording).

You may well think *convene* is better, but that's another thing to the other choice being sloppy. Personally, I'd go for it most of the time, but when it's been done "hastily" I prefer assemble, as its other senses give me an image of something being thrown together in that haste—sloppiness of the organisers, rather than the reporter—that is appropriate.

Comment: Does that mean a "hastily put-together meeting", a "hastily thrown-together meeting", and a "hastily cobbled-together meeting" are acceptable English?

Comment: Yes, but they aren't in the overlap of *convene* and *assemble*. They still work metaphorically and would be good if there were evidence signs of that haste (i.e. if the meeting was a bit of a mess because of the haste). If that was the case, then they'd be **better** than *assemble* or *convene*, but otherwise they wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Both may be either transitive or intransitive, both may mean either gathering the members of a group or the whole group thus gathered. I think it's not so much a matter of logic as that of collocation. 'Convene' and 'conference' go together like hands and gloves while 'assemble' and 'conference' do not, or if ever, like hands and socks.